# How to have different Order ID's or Order Prefix/Suffix for Frontend and Backend Order

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, orders, sales-order, order-grid

We have a unique requirement from one of our client. What is needed is a separate Order Id for Frontend orders and different for backend orders.

The basic necessity is to differentiate between the backend and frontend orders.

I am aware regarding how to change the prefix of the orders from the database, however I am not coming to conclusion regarding what approach can be taken to separate out these orders as whenever the order is placed order id will be an increment order id irrespective of frontend/backend order.

Can anyone please provide an insight on what approach should be taken.

Is there a way to have a different prefix/suffix for these orders? or is there any other way we can differentiate between them?

Comment: are you need order increment id to frontend orders 100000001,100000002.. and backend orders B00000003,B00000004 right?

Comment: Yes, that can be a good solution.. its fine if only prefix/suffix is different

Answer (score 0):

Not a tested idea but there is an approach :
 - add an observer on `sales_order_place_after` in the `adminhtml` node (important) to observe only the backend process. From that you can update the increment ID.
If this is not working you can add a flag in this observer and override the class `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Numeric` where you can use the flag set in the observer